# Using putExtra in intent to display specific layout in new activity

Tags: java, android, layout, android-intent

i am curious how i go about using the

```
putExtra("something", something);
```

in a intent to a new activity inside my application,

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
i.putExtra("something", something)
startActivity(i);
```

I need to know how i would the sending and receiving end would look like, For Loading a specific layout file depending on what was sent via the putExtra in the intent.

So if i send the i.putExtra("a", a) on the receiving end, it would create a content view with R.layout.a_layout.xml

but if i sent i.putExtra("b", b) it would load R.layout.b_layout.xml

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One nifty way of doing this would be to say:

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
i.putExtra("layout", R.layout.a_layout.xml);
```

to send the correct layout to your new class. Then in the new class, you can use:

```
int layout = getIntent().getIntExtra("layout", R.layout.default_layout);
setContentView(layout);
```

Answer (score 2):

Send the int representing your layout:

```
i.putExtra("layout_id", R.layout.my_layout1);
```

and load it

```
setContentView(getIntent().getIntExtra("layout_id", R.layout.default_layout);
```

Answer (score 0):

A value such as `R.layout.a_layout` is just an `int`.  So, just use `putExtra("Key", R.layout.a_layout);`.

Then, on your receiving activity, just pass that same `int` to `setContentView()`, like:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    int layout = getIntent().getIntExtra("Key", -1);
    if (layout != -1)
        setContentView(layout);
}
```